# Numpy array dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimensions

How do I get the dimensions of an array? For instance, this is 2x2:

```py
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
```

Comment: A piece of advice: your "dimensions" are called the `shape`, in NumPy. What NumPy calls the dimension is 2, in your case (`ndim`).  It's useful to know the usual NumPy terminology: this makes reading the docs easier!

Answer (score 580, accepted):

Use [`.shape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html#numpy.ndarray.shape) to obtain a tuple of array dimensions:

```
>>> a.shape
(2, 2)
```

Comment: Note: `shape` might be more accurately described as an *attribute* than as a *function*, since it is not invoked using function-call syntax.

Comment: @nobar actually it is a _property_ (which is both an attribute and a function, really)

Comment: @wim more specifically [property is a class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property). In the case of class properties (a property you put in your class), they are objects of type property exposed as an attribute of the class. An attribute, in python, [is the name following the dot](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).

Comment: If you really want to nitpick, it's a descriptor.  Although `property` itself is a class, `ndarray.shape` is not a class, it's an instance of the property type.

Answer (score 93):

### First:

By convention, in Python world, the shortcut for `numpy` is `np`, so:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
```

### Second：

In Numpy, **dimension**, **axis/axes**, **shape** are related and sometimes similar concepts:

#### dimension

In *Mathematics/Physics*, dimension or dimensionality is informally defined as the minimum number of coordinates needed to specify any point within a space. But in *Numpy*, according to the [numpy doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html#the-basics), it's the same as axis/axes:

> In Numpy dimensions are called axes. The number of axes is rank.

```
In [3]: a.ndim  # num of dimensions/axes, *Mathematics definition of dimension*
Out[3]: 2
```

#### axis/axes

the *nth* coordinate to index an `array` in Numpy. And multidimensional arrays can have one index per axis.

```
In [4]: a[1,0]  # to index `a`, we specific 1 at the first axis and 0 at the second axis.
Out[4]: 3  # which results in 3 (locate at the row 1 and column 0, 0-based index)
```

#### shape

describes how many data (or the range) along each available axis.

```
In [5]: a.shape
Out[5]: (2, 2)  # both the first and second axis have 2 (columns/rows/pages/blocks/...) data
```

Answer (score 49):

```
import numpy as np   
>>> np.shape(a)
(2,2)
```

Also works if the input is not a numpy array but a list of lists

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[1,2]]
>>> np.shape(a)
(2,2)
```

Or a tuple of tuples

```
>>> a = ((1,2),(1,2))
>>> np.shape(a)
(2,2)
```

Comment: `np.shape` first turns its argument into an array if it doesn't have the shape attribute,  That's why it works on the list and tuple examples.

Answer (score 22):

Use `.shape`:

```
In: a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
In: a.shape
Out: (2, 3)
In: a.shape[0] # x axis
Out: 2
In: a.shape[1] # y axis
Out: 3
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use `.ndim` for dimension and `.shape` to know the exact dimension:

```
>>> var = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3,4,5,6]])

>>> var.ndim
2

>>> var.shape
(2, 6)
```

You can change the dimension using `.reshape` function:

```
>>> var_ = var.reshape(3, 4)

>>> var_.ndim
2

>>> var_.shape
(3, 4)
```

Answer (score 8):

The `shape` method requires that `a` be a Numpy ndarray. But Numpy can also calculate the shape of iterables of pure python objects:

```
np.shape([[1,2],[1,2]])
```

Answer (score 3):

`a.shape` is just a limited version of `np.info()`. Check this out:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2],[1,2]])
np.info(a)
```

Out

```
class:  ndarray
shape:  (2, 2)
strides:  (8, 4)
itemsize:  4
aligned:  True
contiguous:  True
fortran:  False
data pointer: 0x27509cf0560
byteorder:  little
byteswap:  False
type: int32
```

Answer (score 1):

```
rows = a.shape[0] # 2 
cols = a.shape[1] # 2
a.shape #(2,2)
a.size # rows * cols = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute below code block in python notebook.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2],[1,2]])
print(a.shape)
print(type(a.shape))
print(a.shape[0])
```

**output**

> (2, 2)

> <class 'tuple'>

> 2

then you realized that `a.shape` is a tuple.
so you can get any dimension's size by `a.shape[index of dimention]`

Answer (score 0):

Since the dimensions of a numpy array is stored as the `shape` attribute, `getattr()` can also be used.

```py
arr = np.arange(8).reshape(2,2,2)
getattr(arr, 'shape')   # (2, 2, 2)
```

It's useful if you need to get it along with a dynamic list of other properties. An example could be

```py
properties = ['shape', 'ndim', 'size']
d = {prop: getattr(arr, prop) for prop in properties}
# {'shape': (2, 2, 2), 'ndim': 3, 'size': 8}
```