# What does axis in pandas mean?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Here is my code to generate a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dff = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1,2),columns=list('AB'))
```

then I got the dataframe:

```
+------------+---------+--------+
|            |  A      |  B     |
+------------+---------+---------
|      0     | 0.626386| 1.52325|
+------------+---------+--------+
```

When I type the commmand :

```
dff.mean(axis=1)
```

I got :

```
0    1.074821
dtype: float64
```

According to the reference of pandas, axis=1 stands for columns and I expect the result of the command to be

```
A    0.626386
B    1.523255
dtype: float64
```

So here is my question: what does axis in pandas mean?

Answer (score 538, accepted):

It specifies the axis **along which** the means are computed. By default `axis=0`. This is consistent with the `numpy.mean` usage when `axis` is specified *explicitly* (in `numpy.mean`, axis==None by default, which computes the mean value over the flattened array) , in which `axis=0` along the *rows* (namely, *index* in pandas), and `axis=1` along the *columns*. For added clarity, one may choose to specify `axis='index'` (instead of `axis=0`) or `axis='columns'` (instead of `axis=1`).

```
+------------+---------+--------+
|            |  A      |  B     |
+------------+---------+---------
|      0     | 0.626386| 1.52325|----axis=1----->
+------------+---------+--------+
             |         |
             | axis=0  |
             ↓         ↓
```

Comment: Usually axis=0 is said to be "column-wise" (and axis=1 "row-wise"), I think "along the rows" is confusing. (Nice "pic" though :) )

Comment: @AndyHayden yeah, but maybe both are a bit confusing, to those who the first time to come across the this ;)

Comment: Also, the reason that `axis=0` indicates aggregating along rows and `axis=1` indicates aggregating along columns is because of how you index into a dataframe. In `df.iloc[row, column]`, `row` is in index position 0 and `column` is in index position 1. [Numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html#calculation) generalizes this to N dimensions, which is where thinking in terms of the axis that the aggregation collapses starts to make more sense than "row-wise" or "column-wise".

Comment: I still feel confusing. If I do `df.drop("A", axis = 1)` then the A __column__ will be dropped. It is not "along the row" nor "row-wise" but dropping column A.

Comment: @ytu `axis=0` means each row as a bulk, we only can manipulate DataFrame inter-row instead of inner-row. `axis=1` means each column as a bulk, we only can manipulate DataFrame inter-column instead of inner-column. So if you use `df.drop("A", axis = 1)`, it will drop a whole column.

Comment: The words of this answer make sense but the little table example looks backwards (I'm not saying it is, because I don't really see how he was using it, but it looks backwards to me). 0=rows, 1=columns.

Comment: @TomQ The `column` for `df.ioc[row,column]` is in position1 but the  `mean(foo,axis=1)` is aggregating on the row. This still seems contradictory.

Comment: @javadba the mean aggregation in your example collapses the column dimension, leaving only rows behind. `axis=1` indicates the dimension to collapse.

Comment: @zhangxaochen: Thanks for the answer, but I wonder why in `apply()`, `axis = 0` means  *apply function to each column*. I'm confused at this. From my thought, it should be `axis=1`. Can you please explain. Thanks

Comment: @Catbuilts, you may first read the docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html; and then this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773245/ambiguity-in-pandas-dataframe-numpy-array-axis-definition/25774395

Comment: @zhangxaochen. one question, why we have to use pd.drop('col_name', axis=1, inplace=True) , when a column need to be droped?

Comment: I think "along" should be replaced with "across". To go along something (e.g. road) to me means to stay on it, but with axis=0 we don't stay on the same row when, say, calculating the mean; rather we go across all the rows in a column.

Comment: by default it's none that means compute on all values.

Comment: axis = 0 (downward), axis = 1 (right direction). To apply any operation downward use axis = 0; To apply any operation on right direction use axis =1. This is my trick to remember and avoid confusion.

Comment: @TomQ. Does that reason make `axis=1` to be dropping `col` in `pandas.DataFrame.drop`? This confused me before I find your comment.

Comment: I want function to apply to each **row**, so I intuitively make `df.apply(f, axis='rows')` which gives an opposite result, applying `f()` to each column. This is a great example of what *counterintuitive* means.

Comment: > "I think "along" should be replaced with "across"." -- Except when you start using other functions like `concat()`. I prefer _"row-wise"_, and _"column-wise"_.

Answer (score 204):

These answers do help explain this, but it still isn't perfectly intuitive for a non-programmer (i.e. someone like me who is learning Python for the first time in context of data science coursework). I still find using the terms "along" or "for each" wrt to rows and columns to be confusing.

What makes more sense to me is to say it this way:

- Axis 0 will act on all the ROWS in each COLUMN
- Axis 1 will act on all the COLUMNS in each ROW

So a mean on axis 0 will be the mean of all the rows in each column, and a mean on axis 1 will be a mean of all the columns in each row.

Ultimately this is saying the same thing as @zhangxaochen and @Michael, but in a way that is easier for me to internalize.

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the complexity of each so-called "act". df.dropna(axis=0) will first check all the COLUMNS in each ROW and then drop those ROWS with a null.  The axis talks about the last step but our brain will focus on the first part.

Answer (score 134):

**Let's visualize (you gonna remember always),** 
[image]

In Pandas:

1. axis=0 means along "indexes". It's a **row-wise operation**.

Suppose, to perform concat() operation on dataframe1 & dataframe2,
we will take dataframe1 & take out 1st row from dataframe1 and place into the new DF, then we take out another row from dataframe1 and put into new DF, we repeat this process until we reach to the bottom of dataframe1. Then, we do the same process for dataframe2.

Basically, stacking dataframe2 on top of dataframe1 or vice a versa.

**E.g making a pile of books on a table or floor**

2. axis=1 means along "columns". It's a **column-wise operation.**

Suppose, to perform concat() operation on dataframe1 & dataframe2,
we will take out the 1st **complete column**(a.k.a 1st series) of dataframe1 and place into new DF, then we take out the second column of dataframe1 and keep adjacent to it **(sideways)**, we have to repeat this operation until all columns are finished. Then, we repeat the same process on dataframe2.
Basically, 
**stacking dataframe2 sideways.**

**E.g arranging books on a bookshelf.**

> More to it, since arrays are better representations to represent a nested n-dimensional structure compared to matrices! so below can help you more to visualize how axis plays an important role when you generalize to more than one dimension. Also, you can actually print/write/draw/visualize any n-dim array but, writing or visualizing the same in a matrix representation(3-dim) is impossible on a paper more than 3-dimensions.

[image]

Comment: I think this answer is the proper one. You need to visualize it. 
axis=0 (or axis='rows' is horizontal axis. 
axis=1 (or axis='columns') is vertical axis.
To take it further, if you use pandas method drop, to remove columns or rows, if you specify axis=1 you will be removing columns. If you specify axis=0 you will be removing rows from dataset.
So if we have some pandas dataframe in variable df:
df.drop(0, axis=0) will remove the whole first row of dataset
df.drop('grades', axis=1) will remove column 'grades' from dataset
Hope this clarifies it little bit more...

Comment: @Roboblob -- still confusing. df.drop(n, axis=1) acts on a column. Why doesn't df.mean(axis=1) take action on a column?

Comment: @matty, first! have your hands dirty!, it's so straight forward. For your reference, [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) &[mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html), axis=1 is same for both, please ask a new question if you haven't understood something in your example!

Comment: @anu -- hands dirty? We don't need to clutter SO with duplicate questions. I'm confident that one or more answers on this page can be clarified to reduce this confusion. I'd do it myself if I could, but for right now, I only know how to use them. I do understand which axis to use to get the data I want. However confusion remains as to why mean() and drop() feel like they affect opposing axes.

Comment: I'm afraid this answer is incredibly confusing. You talk about acting on rows as being axis=0 yet you draw red arrows going down columns. You talk about axis=1 acting on columns, yet you draw arrows going across a row. Whoever came up with this system didn't think it through very well.

Comment: Agreeing with @rocksNwaves, I'm not convinced this is a useful visualization either. It may make more sense to think of it as `axis='index'/'columns'` instead of `axis=0/1`. `axis='index'` means you are moving _vertically down_ along the index. `axis='columns'` means you are moving _horizontally right_ along the columns. Put in perspective your bookshelf visualization is counterintuitive.

Answer (score 44):

`axis` refers to the dimension of the array, in the case of `pd.DataFrame`s `axis=0` is the dimension that points downwards and `axis=1` the one that points to the right.

**Example:** Think of an `ndarray` with shape `(3,5,7)`.

```
a = np.ones((3,5,7))
```

`a` is a 3 dimensional `ndarray`, i.e. it has **3 axes** ("axes" is plural of "axis"). The configuration of `a` will look like 3 slices of bread where each slice is of dimension 5-by-7. `a[0,:,:]` will refer to the 0-th slice, `a[1,:,:]` will refer to the 1-st slice etc.

`a.sum(axis=0)` will apply `sum()` along the 0-th axis of `a`. You will add all the slices and end up with one slice of shape `(5,7)`.

`a.sum(axis=0)` is equivalent to

```
b = np.zeros((5,7))
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(7):
        b[i,j] += a[:,i,j].sum()
```

`b` and `a.sum(axis=0)` will both look like this

```
array([[ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.]])
```

In a `pd.DataFrame`, axes work the same way as in `numpy.array`s: `axis=0` will apply `sum()` or any other reduction function for each column.

**N.B.** In @zhangxaochen's answer, I find the phrases "along the rows" and "along the columns" slightly confusing. `axis=0` should refer to "along each column", and `axis=1` "along each row".

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one - since as Safak mentions the phrases used there are poorly worded and leading to yet more confusion.

Comment: This is the better answer

Answer (score 34):

Let's look at the table from Wiki. This is an IMF estimate of GDP from 2010 to 2019 for top ten countries.
[image]

**1. Axis 1 will act for each row on all the columns** 
 If you want to calculate the average (mean) GDP for EACH countries over the decade (2010-2019), you need to do, `df.mean(axis=1)`. For example, if you want to calculate mean GDP of United States from 2010 to 2019, `df.loc['United States','2010':'2019'].mean(axis=1)`

**2. Axis 0 will act for each column on all the rows**
 If I want to calculate the average (mean) GDP for EACH year for all countries, you need to do, `df.mean(axis=0)`. For example, if you want to calculate mean GDP of the year 2015 for United States, China, Japan, Germany and India, `df.loc['United States':'India','2015'].mean(axis=0)` 

**Note:** The above code will work only after setting "Country(or dependent territory)" column as the Index, using `set_index` method.

Answer (score 32):

The easiest way for me to understand is to talk about whether you are calculating a statistic for each column (`axis = 0`) or each row (`axis = 1`). If you calculate a statistic, say a mean, with `axis = 0` you will get that statistic for each column. So if each observation is a row and each variable is in a column, you would get the mean of each variable. If you set `axis = 1` then you will calculate your statistic for each row. In our example, you would get the mean for each observation across all of your variables (perhaps you want the average of related measures).

`axis = 0`: by column = column-wise = along the rows

`axis = 1`: by row = row-wise = along the columns

Comment: I think "along" should be replaced with "across". To go along something (e.g. road) to me means to stay on it, but with `axis=0` we don't stay on the say row when, say, calculating the mean; rather we go across all the rows in a column.

Answer (score 16):

Axis in view of programming is the position in the shape tuple. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.arange(120).reshape(2,3,4,5)

a.shape
Out[3]: (2, 3, 4, 5)

np.sum(a,axis=0).shape
Out[4]: (3, 4, 5)

np.sum(a,axis=1).shape
Out[5]: (2, 4, 5)

np.sum(a,axis=2).shape
Out[6]: (2, 3, 5)

np.sum(a,axis=3).shape
Out[7]: (2, 3, 4)
```

Mean on the axis will cause that dimension to be removed.

Referring to the original question, the dff shape is (1,2). Using axis=1 will change the shape to (1,).

Answer (score 15):

The designer of pandas, Wes McKinney, used to work intensively on finance data. Think of columns as stock names and index as daily prices. You can then guess what the default behavior is (i.e., `axis=0`) with respect to this finance data. `axis=1` can be simply thought as 'the other direction'.

For example, the statistics functions, such as `mean()`, `sum()`, `describe()`, `count()` all default to column-wise because it makes more sense to do them for each stock. `sort_index(by=)` also defaults to column. `fillna(method='ffill')` will fill along column because it is the same stock. `dropna()` defaults to row because you probably just want to discard the price on that day instead of throw away all prices of that stock.

Similarly, the square brackets indexing refers to the columns since it's more common to pick a stock instead of picking a day.

Comment: your reasoning sounds right but mean(), sum() and other functions default to (axis = 0) which is row-wise and not as mentioned above. And row-wise seems to behave like we expect column-wise :) and that seems to be the confusion.

Answer (score 14):

The problem with using `axis=` properly is for its use for 2 main different cases:

1. For computing an *accumulated value*, or *rearranging* (e. g. sorting) data.
2. For *manipulating* ("playing" with) *entities* (e. g. *dataframes*).

The main idea behind this answer is that for avoiding the confusion, we select either a *number*, or a *name* for specifying the particular axis, *whichever is more clear, intuitive, and descriptive.*

Pandas is based on NumPy, which is based on mathematics, particularly on n-dimensional matrices. Here is an image for common use of axes' names in math in the 3-dimensional space:

[image]
This picture is for memorizing the *axes' ordinal numbers* only:

- `0` for x-axis,
- `1` for y-axis, and
- `2` for z-axis.

The *z-axis* is only for *panels*; for *dataframes* we will restrict our interest to the green-colored, *2-dimensional basic plane* with *x-axis (`0`, vertical)*, and *y-axis (`1`, horizontal).*

[image]
It's all for *numbers* as potential values of `axis=` parameter.

The *names* of axes are `'index'` (you may use the alias `'rows'`) and `'columns'`, and for this explanation *it is NOT important the relation between these names and ordinal numbers* (of axes),  as  everybody knows what the words *"rows"* and *"columns"* mean (and everybody *here* — I suppose — knows what the word *"index"* in pandas means).

**And now, my recommendation:**

1. If you want to **compute an accumulated value**, you may compute it from values located **along axis 0** (or **along axis 1**) — use `axis=0` (or `axis=1`).

   Similarly, if you want to **rearrange values**, use **the axis number** of the axis, **along which** are located data for rearranging (e.g. for *sorting*).
2. If you want to **manipulate** (e.g. *concatenate*) **entities** (e.g. *dataframes*) — use `axis='index'` (synonym: `axis='rows'`) or `axis='columns'` to specify the *resulting change* — **index** (**rows**) or **columns**, respectively.
   (For *concatenating*, you will obtain either a *longer index (= more rows)*, or *more columns*, respectively.)

Comment: this is the very best answer, and should probably be marked as the correct answer by the op!

Answer (score 12):

I used to get confused with this as well, but this is how I remember it.

**It specifies the dimension of the dataframe that would change or on which the operation would be performed.**

Let us understand this with an example.
We have a dataframe `df` and it has shape as (5, 10), meaning it has 5 rows and 10 columns.

Now when we do `df.mean(axis=1)` it means that dimension 1 would be changed, this implies that it would have the same number of rows but a different number of columns. Hence the result that would get would be of the shape (5, 1).

Similarly, if we do `df.mean(axis=0)` it means that dimension 0 would be changed, meaning the number of rows would be changed but the number of columns would remain the same, hence the result would be of shape (1, 10).

Try to relate this with the examples provided in the question.

Comment: This is the best, most clear answer I see so far

Comment: This is why `df.apply(my_func, axis=1)` gives `my_func` the row as an argument even though rows are axis 0: so you can change the columns.

Answer (score 6):

one of easy ways to remember axis 1 (columns), vs axis 0 (rows) is the output you expect.

- if you expect an output for each row you use axis='columns',
- on the other hand if you want an output for each column you use axis='rows'.

Comment: Thanks. This, however, only works for computation right? It wouldn't work for methods such as `pd.concat` or `df.dropna()`, which uses the kewarg axis in more of an identification capacity.

Answer (score 5):

I believe, the correct answer should be "**it is complicated**"

**[1] The term "axis" iteself conjures different mental image in different people**
lets say the y-axis, it should conjure up an image of something vertical. However, now think of a vertical line `x=0`. it is vertical line too, yet it is **addressed** by a value `0` on the x-axis.

Similarly, when we say `axis='index'` (meaning `axis=0`), are we saying the "vertical" direction that indexes reside on? or that one series of data **addressed** by an index value? Panda tends to mean the first meaning, the vertical direction.

**[2] Pandas itself is not 100% consistent either, observe the following cases, they ALMOST have the same common theme:**

```
# [1] piling dfs
pd.concat([df0, df1], axis='index') 
    # adding dfs on top of each other vertically like pilling up a column, 
    # but, we will use the word 'index'

# [2] for every column in df: operate on it
df.apply(foo, axis='index')     # apply func foo to one column at a time
df.mean('A', axis='index')      # apply "mean()" to one column at a time
a_boolean_df.all(axis='index')  # check if each column contains only bool "True"
    # apply an operation to a vertical slice of data, ie. a column, 
    # then apply the same operation to the next column on the right 
    # then to the right again... until the last column
    # but, we will use the word 'index'

# [3] delete a column or row of data
df.drop(axis='index', ...)
df.dropna(axis='index', ...)
    # this time, we are droping an index/row, a horizontal slice of data.
    # so OBVIOUSLY we will use the word 'index'

# [4] when you iterate thru a df naturally, what would show up first? a row or a column?
for x in df:
    # x == a column's name

# [5] drop duplicate
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['mycolumn0', 'mycolumn1']...)
    # thank God we don't need to deal with the "axis" bs in this
```

Comment: I agree. It seems that people think it's simple, but it always confuses me. Also, I don't see a page in the docs explaining the "axis" argument, which is maybe a sign that the pandas team itself doesn't have a great way to explain it.

Answer (score 4):

This is based on @Safak's answer.
The best way to understand the axes in pandas/numpy is to create a 3d array and check the result of the sum function along the 3 different axes.

```
 a = np.ones((3,5,7))
```

a will be:

```
    array([[[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

   [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]],

   [[1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.],
    [1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]]])
```

Now check out the sum of elements of the array along each of the axes:

```
 x0 = np.sum(a,axis=0)
 x1 = np.sum(a,axis=1)
 x2 = np.sum(a,axis=2)
```

will give you the following results:

```
   x0 :
   array([[3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
        [3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
        [3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
        [3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.],
        [3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3., 3.]])

   x1 : 
   array([[5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
   [5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.],
   [5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5., 5.]])

  x2 :
   array([[7., 7., 7., 7., 7.],
        [7., 7., 7., 7., 7.],
        [7., 7., 7., 7., 7.]])
```

Answer (score 4):

On important thing to keep in mind it that when you are using functions such as mean, median etc., you are basically doing **numpy aggregation**. Think of aggregation as getting a final single output, which can be column wise, row wise or a single number for the entire dataset.

So when we say aggregation in arrays, say `numpy.sum(data, axis = 0)`, what we really mean is that we want to remove that particular axis (here 0 axis).

[image: Numpy Axis Illustration]

**Example:** For this particular dataset if we compute the sum by axis = 0, we are actually interested in removing (aggregating) the zero axis. Once we remove the zero axis, the aggregation along zero axis will lead to [1,4,3] being equal to 8, [2,3,6] to 11 and [5,7,9] to 21. Similar logic can be extended to axis = 1.

> In case of drop, concat and some other functions, we are actually not
> aggregating the results.

**The mental model I use for intuition:**

Think that we have placed a Kangaroo/Frog in each of the cells in the first column when axis = 0 or along the first row if axis = 1.

**Case:** When axis = zero

[image: First Step]

Think of plus green shape as a frog.

> Axis zero means movement along the rows

**Sum:** Say we are computing sum, then first they will compute the sum of their positions (r1c1, r2c1, r3c1) [1,4,3] = [8]. Then their next move will also be along the row as axis = 0. Their new positions are in the next pic (below).

**Drop:** If along the row they encounter any NaN in (r1c1, r2c1, r3c1), they will remove the corresponding row as axis = 0

[image: Second Step]

**Sum:** Now again, they will compute the sum of their positions (r1c2, r2c2, r3c2) [2,3,6] = [11] and similarly they will move one step forward along the row and compute the sum for the third column [21].

**Drop:** If along the row they encounter any NaN in (r1c2, r2c2, r3c2), they will remove the corresponding row as axis = 0. Similar logic can be extended for different axis and additional rows/columns.

[image: Third Step]

Answer (score 3):

There're two most common usage of axis on Pandas:

1. used as indexing, like `df.iloc[0, 1]`
2. used as argument inside a function, like `df.mean(axis=1)`

While using as indexing, we can interpret that axis=0 stands for rows and axis=1 stands for columns, which is `df.iloc[rows, columns]`. So, `df.iloc[0, 1]` means selecting the data from row 0 and column 1, in this case, it returns 1.52325.

While using as argument, axis=0 means selecting object across rows vertically, and axis=1 means selecting object across columns horizontally.

[image: axis]

So, `df.mean(axis=1)` stands for calculating mean across columns horizontally, and it returns:

```
0    1.074821
dtype: float64
```

The general purpose of axis is used for selecting specific data to operate on. And the key for understanding axis, is to **separate the process of "selection" and "operation"**.

Let's explain it with 1 extra cases: `df.drop('A', axis=1)`

1. The operation is `df.drop()`, it requires the name of the intended
   column, which is 'A' in this case. It's not the same as `df.mean()`
   that operating on data content.
2. The selection is the name of column, not the data content of column. Since all column names are arranged across columns horizontally, so we use `axis=1` to select the name object.

In short, we better separate the "selection" and "operation" to have a clear understanding on:

1. what object to select
2. how is it arranged

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying to figure out the axis for the last hour as well. The language in all the above answers, and also the documentation is not at all helpful.

To answer the question as I understand it now, in Pandas, axis = 1 or 0 means which **axis headers** do you want to keep constant when applying the function.

Note: When I say headers, I mean index names

Expanding your example:

```
+------------+---------+--------+
|            |  A      |  B     |
+------------+---------+---------
|      X     | 0.626386| 1.52325|
+------------+---------+--------+
|      Y     | 0.626386| 1.52325|
+------------+---------+--------+
```

For axis=1=columns : We keep columns headers constant and apply the mean function by changing data.
To demonstrate, we keep the columns headers constant as:

```
+------------+---------+--------+
|            |  A      |  B     |
```

Now we populate one set of A and B values and then find the mean

```
|            | 0.626386| 1.52325|
```

Then we populate next set of A and B values and find the mean

```
|            | 0.626386| 1.52325|
```

Similarly, for axis=rows, we keep row headers constant, and keep changing the data:
To demonstrate, first fix the row headers:

```
+------------+
|      X     |
+------------+
|      Y     |
+------------+
```

Now populate first set of X and Y values and then find the mean

```
+------------+---------+
|      X     | 0.626386
+------------+---------+
|      Y     | 0.626386
+------------+---------+
```

Then populate the next set of X and Y values and then find the mean:

```
+------------+---------+
|      X     | 1.52325 |
+------------+---------+
|      Y     | 1.52325 |
+------------+---------+
```

In summary,

When axis=columns, you fix the column headers and change data, which will come from the different rows.

When axis=rows, you fix the row headers and change data, which will come from the different columns.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

[image]

axis=1 ,It will give the sum row wise,keepdims=True will maintain the 2D dimension.
Hope it helps you.

Comment: Not OP but thanks. I think the majority of the confusion that people have about this is, in Pandas's documentary, axis = 1 corresponds to columns. However, here it's doing 'row-wise' calculation.

Comment: Consider that pandas `df.apply(np.sum, axis=1)` will have the same effect as the numpy operation. "Row-wise" sum but we use `axis=1` or equivalently `axis="columns"`.  I.e there the axis=1 kwarg means "across columns" and does NOT mean "along a column".

Answer (score 2):

Actually we don't need to hard remember what `axis=0, axis=1` represents for.
As sometimes, axis can be a tuple: e.g.`axis=(0,1)` How do we understand such multiple dim axis?

I found if we understand how **python slice [:]** works, it would be easier.

Suppose we have an 1d array:
`a = [ 0, 1, 0 ]`

```
a[:] # select all the elements in array a
```

Suppose we have a 2d array:

```
M = [[0, 0, 1],
     [1, 0, 0],
     [0, 2, 1],
     [2, 0, 2],
     [3, 1, 0]]
M[1,:] # M[0]=1, M[1]=* --> [1, 0, 0]
M[:,2] # M[0]=*, M[1]=2 --> [1, 0, 1, 2, 0]
M[:,:] # M[0]=*, M[1]=* --> all the elements in M are selected
```

So when computes:

```
np.sum(M, axis=0) # [sum(M[:,0]), sum(M[:,1]), sum(M[:,2])]
np.sum(M, axis=1) # [sum(M[0,:]), sum(M[1,:]), sum(M[2,:]), sum(M[3,:]), sum(M[4,:])]
np.sum(M, axis=-1) # -1 means last dim, it's the same with np.sum(M, axis=1)
np.sum(M, axis=(0,1)) # sum(M[:,:])
```

The rule is simple, replace the dims specified in `axis` as `:` when computes.

Answer (score 1):

axis = 0 means up to down 
axis = 1 means left to right

```
sums[key] = lang_sets[key].iloc[:,1:].sum(axis=0)
```

Given example is taking sum of all the data in column == key.

Answer (score 1):

My thinking : Axis = n, where n = 0, 1, etc. means that the matrix is collapsed (folded) along that axis. So in a 2D matrix, when you collapse along 0 (rows), you are really operating on one column at a time. Similarly for higher order matrices.

This is not the same as the normal reference to a dimension in a matrix, where 0 -> row and 1 -> column. Similarly for other dimensions in an N dimension array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a newbie to pandas. But this is how I understand axis in pandas:

---

**Axis**   **Constant**     **Varying**      **Direction**

---

0     Column            Row          Downwards |

---

1           Row          Column     Towards Right -->

---

So to compute mean of a column, that particular column should be **constant** but the rows under that can change **(varying)** so it is axis=0.

Similarly, to compute mean of a row, that particular row is **constant** but it can traverse through different columns **(varying)**, axis=1.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this way :

Say if your operation requires traversing from **left to right/right to left** in a dataframe, you are apparently merging columns ie. you are operating on various columns.
This is **axis =1**

**Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(12).reshape(3,4),columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
print(df)
   A  B   C   D
0  0  1   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11 

df.mean(axis=1)

0    1.5
1    5.5
2    9.5
dtype: float64

df.drop(['A','B'],axis=1,inplace=True)

    C   D
0   2   3
1   6   7
2  10  11
```

> Point to note here is we are operating on columns

Similarly, if your operation requires traversing from **top to bottom/bottom to top** in a dataframe, you are merging rows. This is **axis=0**.

Answer (score 1):

I will explicitly avoid using 'row-wise' or 'along the columns', since people may interpret them in exactly the wrong way.

Analogy first. Intuitively, you would expect that `pandas.DataFrame.drop(axis='column')` drops a column from N columns and gives you (N - 1) columns. So you can pay NO attention to rows for now (and remove word 'row' from your English dictionary.) Vice versa, `drop(axis='row')` works on rows.

In the same way, `sum(axis='column')` works on multiple columns and gives you 1 column. Similarly, `sum(axis='row')` results in 1 row. This is consistent with its simplest form of definition, reducing a list of numbers to a single number.

**In general, with `axis=column`, you see columns, work on columns, and get columns. Forget rows.**

With `axis=row`, change perspective and work on rows.

0 and 1 are just aliases for 'row' and 'column'. It's the convention of matrix indexing.

Comment: This interpretation is not correct using axis='columns' doesn't give you columns.

Comment: @user3065757 Thanks for the comments. Could you please elaborate with examples?

Comment: Not who you are replying to, but when I try to figure out `pd.concat` with your explanation, it doesn't quite work. Could you explain the concat behavior with the 2 axes please? Thanks.

Comment: @BowenLiu When you concat 2 lists of apples, you get 1 list of more apples (but not bigger apples). When you concat rows (axis=0), you get more rows (not longer rows); when you concat columns (axis=1), you get more columns (not longer columns). The idea is axis=0 operates between rows, not inside a row.

Answer (score 1):

Say for example, if you use **df.shape** then you will get a tuple containing the number of rows & columns in the data frame as the output.

```
In [10]: movies_df.shape
Out[10]: (1000, 11)
```

In the example above, there are 1000 rows & 11 columns in the movies data frame where 'row' is mentioned in the index 0 position & 'column' in the index 1 position of the tuple. Hence 'axis=1' denotes column & 'axis=0' denotes row.

Credits: [Github](https://github.com/LearnDataSci/articles/blob/master/Python%20Pandas%20Tutorial%20A%20Complete%20Introduction%20for%20Beginners/notebook.ipynb)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an another way to understand it.

For a np.array,if we want eliminate columns we use axis = 1; if we want eliminate rows, we use axis = 0.

```
np.mean(np.array(np.ones(shape=(3,5,10))),axis = 0).shape # (5,10)
np.mean(np.array(np.ones(shape=(3,5,10))),axis = 1).shape # (3,10)
np.mean(np.array(np.ones(shape=(3,5,10))),axis = (0,1)).shape # (10,)
```

For pandas object, `axis = 0` stands for row-wise operation and `axis = 1` stands for column-wise operation. This is different from `numpy` by definition, we can check definitions from [numpy.doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) and [pandas.doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Answer (score 0):

Many answers here helped me a lot!

In case you get confused by the different behaviours of `axis` in Python and `MARGIN` in R (like in the `apply` function), you may find a blog post that I wrote of interest: https://accio.github.io/programming/2020/05/19/numpy-pandas-axis.html.

In essence:

- Their behaviours are, intriguingly, easier to understand with three-dimensional array than with two-dimensional arrays.
- In Python packages `numpy` and `pandas`, the axis parameter in sum actually specifies numpy to calculate the mean of all values that can be fetched in the form of array[0, 0, ..., i, ..., 0] where i iterates through all possible values. The process is repeated with the position of i fixed and the indices of other dimensions vary one after the other (from the most far-right element). The result is a n-1-dimensional array.
- In R, the MARGINS parameter let the `apply` function calculate the mean of all values that can be fetched in the form of array[, ... , i, ... ,] where i iterates through all possible values. The process is not repeated when all i values have been iterated. Therefore, the result is a simple vector.

Answer (score 0):

Taking on the example from @jerry_sjtu:

```
    +------------+---------+--------+
    |            |  A      |  B     |
    +------------+---------+---------
    |      0     | 0.626386| 1.52325|
    +------------+---------+--------+
```

Pandas docs likely solve the half of the problem as below (it is performing the mean of the rows for each columns):

```
axis{0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0
    Axis along which the function is applied:
        0 or ‘index’: apply function to each column.
        1 or ‘columns’: apply function to each row.
```

`dff.mean(axis='index')` will give the expected answer (it is performing **mean of values along row** - there is only one row, so mean is same as the row values). Remarkably Pandas also gave the **Column label** reducing the ambiguity:

```
A    0.626386
B    1.523255
dtype: float64
```

Whereas, `dff.mean(axis='column')` will give (it is performing **mean of values along columns** - there are two columns so mean is calcualted: 0.62.. + 1.75..=/2 => 1.07..). Remarkably Pandas also gave the **Index label, ie "0"**, reducing the ambiguity:

```
0    1.074821
dtype: float64
```

**Takeaway**: Perhaps using English, ie, axis='column', 'column' instead of '1' would make it less confusing - and wording it as ...*values along <specified label, eg columns>*! Other is referring the manual pages. One can validate the operation by checking the results where it will have column or index names.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Answer (score -10):

Arrays are designed with so-called axis=0 and rows positioned vertically versus axis=1 and columns positioned horizontally. Axis refers to the dimension of the array.
[image: Illustration]

Comment: `axis=0` means each row as a bulk, we only can manipulate DataFrame inter-row instead of inner-row. `axis=1` means each column as a bulk, we only can manipulate DataFrame inter-column instead of inner-column.

Comment: Isn't this exactly the wrong way around according to almost all other descriptions on this page (and according to a quick test with pandas in Jupyter)?

Comment: This is precisely opposite. Please correct your answer.

Comment: Hey @patrick it will be good if you delete this answer, this might confuse peoples :)