# torch.cat along negative dimension

Tags: python, pytorch, numpy-ndarray, tensor, torchvision

In the following,

```
 x_6 = torch.cat((x_1, x_2_1, x_3_1, x_5_1), dim=-3)
 Sizes of tensors x_1, x_2_1, x_3_1, x_5_1 are
 torch.Size([1, 256, 7, 7])
 torch.Size([1, 256, 7, 7]) 
 torch.Size([1, 256, 7, 7])
 torch.Size([1, 256, 7, 7]) respectively.
        
 The size of x_6 turns out to be torch.Size([1, 1024, 7, 7])
```

I couldn't understand & visualise this concatenation along a negative dimension(-3 in this case).
What exactly is happening here?
How does the same go if dim = 3?
Is there any constraint on dim for a given set of tensors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [answer by danin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64430334/2956066) is not completely correct, actually *wrong* when looked from the perspective of tensor algebra, since the answer indicates that the problem has to do with accessing or indexing a Python list. It isn't.

The `-3` means that we concatenate the tensors along the 2<sup>nd</sup> dimension. (you could've very well used 1 instead of the confusing -3).

---

From taking a closer look at the tensor shapes, it seems that they represent `(b, c, h, w)` where `b` stands for batch_size, `c` stands for number of channels, `h` stands for height and `w` stands for width.

This is usually the case, somewhere at the final stages of encoding (possibly) images in a deep neural network and we arrive at these feature maps.

The `torch.cat()` operation with `dim=-3` is meant to say that we concatenate these 4 tensors along the dimension of channels `c` (see above).

4 * 256 => 1024

Hence, the resultant tensor ends up with a shape `torch.Size([1, 1024, 7, 7])`.

---

**Notes**: It is hard to visualize a 4 dimensional space since we humans live in an inherently 3D world. Nevertheless, here are some answers that I wrote a while ago which will help to get some mental picture.

- [How to understand the term `tensor` in TensorFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48235072)
- [Very Basic Numpy array dimension visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48201175)

Answer (score 2):

Python provides negative indexing, so you can access elements starting from the end of the list e.g, -1 is the last element of a list.
In this case the tensor has 4 dimensions, so -3 is actually the 2nd element.