# How axis are defined in 2d matrix in numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, delete-row

I have recently learned NumPy array and I am confused axis=0 and axis =1 represent?
I have searched on the internet and got that axis=0 represent rows and axis=1 represent columns 
but when I start doing some practice I got confused about how axis work differently on two different function 
np.delete() and np.sum()

```
 #input

import numpy as np
arr = np.array([(1,2,3,4),(5,6,7,8),(9,10,11,12)])
print(arr)
print(np.sum(arr,0)[1])

#output

 [[ 1  2  3  4]
  [ 5  6  7  8]
  [ 9 10 11 12]]
 18
```

if axis=0 represent row then it should add 2nd row(row of index 1 ) i.e 5+6+7+8

but instead, it is adding 2nd column i.e 2+6+10

but when I use np.delete()

```
   #input

   print(np.delete(arr,2,0))

   #output

  [[1 2 3 4]
   [5 6 7 8]]
```

here it is deleting 3rd row(row of index 2).

In the first case, axis=0 is working as a column and in the second it is working as row

can you tell me where am I wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the axis parameter from NumPy work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320534/how-does-the-axis-parameter-from-numpy-work)

Comment: The role of `axis` in `sum` (and other 'reduce' functions) can be confusing when working with a 2d array.  It's easier to visualize when working with a 1d or 3d.  With 3d, `sum` on one axis leaves the other two.  `delete` is not a reduction function, so won't help in understanding `sum`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a matter of perspective on how you think about row/column operations. Look at the following diagram ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22320534/how-does-the-axis-parameter-from-numpy-work)):

[image]

According to [`numpy.sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html), the `axis` argument represents the "axis or axes along which a sum is performed". Writing `numpy.sum(arr, axis=0)` translates to *add numbers along each row (0th axis)*. The result is a sum of each column, but the operation is performed row-wise - *for each row*.

The docs for [`numpy.delete`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) state that the `axis` argument represents "the axis along which to delete the subarray". Writing `numpy.delete(arr, 2, axis=0)` means *delete the third element (index=2) from the perspective of the rows (0th axis)*.

It's not a matter of inconsistency: both `numpy.sum` and `numpy.delete` with `axis=0` act over rows (0th index). The first sums the elements across all rows, while the latter removes elements of a specific row.

Comment: So basically it means python reads np.sum(arr,0)[1]  as sum of  2nd element of each row in arr and np.delete(arr,1,0) as delete the second row in arr.

Comment: More specifically, it reads it as "add all of the elements of each row, and then show me what's the second value for the resulting array" (corresponds to the second column of the original array).