# Why does 'dimension' mean several different things in the machine-learning world?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, word-embedding

I've noticed that AI community refers to various tensors as 512-d, meaning 512 dimensional tensor, where the term 'dimension' seems to mean 512 different float values in the representation for a single datapoint. e.g. in 512-d word-embeddings means 512 length vector of floats used to represent 1 english-word e.g. https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/nlp-word-embedding-glove-5e7f523999f6

But it isn't 512 different dimensions, it's only 1 dimensional vector? Why is the term `dimension` used in such a different manner than usual?

When we use the term `conv1d` or `conv2d` which are convolutions over 1-dimension and 2-dimensions, a dimension is used in the typical way it's used in math/sciences but in the word-embedding context, a 1-d vector is said to be a 512-d vector, or am I missing something?

Why is this overloaded use of the term `dimension`? What context determines what `dimension` means in machine-learning as the term seems overloaded?

Comment: Many terms are "overloaded" in that sense and so is almost every symbol throughout the scientific world. There's only a finite amount of useful words for each context, so at some point overloading becomes unavoidable. By the way, Numpy uses the term `shape` and PyTorch uses `size`, to denote the `n` of a n-tensor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of *word embeddings* in neural networks, *dimensionality reduction*, and many other machine learning areas, it is indeed correct to call the vector (which is typically, an 1D array or tensor) as **n-dimensional** where **`n`** is usually greater than 2. This is because we usually work in the [Euclidean space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space) where a (data) *point* in a certain dimensional (Euclidean) space is represented as an [n-tuple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple) of real numbers (i.e. real n-space ℝ<sup>n</sup>).

Below is an example<sup>ref</sup> of a (data) point in a 3D (Euclidean) space. To represent any point in this space, say `d`<sub>1</sub>, we need a tuple of three real numbers (`x`<sub>1</sub>, `y`<sub>1</sub>, `z`<sub>1</sub>).

[image: a point in 3D (Euclidean) space]

Now, your confusion arises why this point `d`<sub>1</sub> is called as 3 dimensional instead of 1 dimensional array. The reason is because it *lies* or *lives* in this 3D space. The same argument can be extended to all points in any n-dimensional real space, as it is done in the case of embeddings with `300d`, `512d`, `1024d` vector etc.

However, in all *nD* array compute frameworks such as NumPy, PyTorch, TensorFlow etc, these are still 1D arrays because the *length* of the above said vectors can be represented using a single number.

But, what if you have more than 1 data point? Then, you have to stack them in some (unique) way. And this is where the need for a second dimension arises. So, let's say you stack 4 of these `512d` vectors vertically, then you'd end up with a 2D array/tensor of shape `(4, 512)`. Note that here we call the array as 2D because two integer numbers are required to represent the extent/length along each axis.

To understand this better, please refer my other answer on [axis parameter visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48177457) for *nD* arrays, the visual representation of which I will include it below.

[image: axis parameter visualization]

---

<sup>ref</sup>: [Euclidean space wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space)

Answer (score 2):

It is not overloading, but standard usage. What are the elements of a 512-dimensional vector space? They are 512 dimensional *vectors*. Each of which can be represented by 512 floating point number as in your equation. Each such vector spans a 1-dimensional subspace of the 512-dimensional space.

When you talk of the dimension of a *tensor*, a tensor is a linear map (roughly speaking, I am omitting the duals) from the product of **N** vector spaces to the reals. The dimension of a TENSOR is the N.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. A 512-d word-embedding for a word say 'cat' is a 1-demensional vector of length 512. isn't that different from a 512 dimension tensor?

Comment: A word embedding lives in a 512-dimensional vector space. a 512 dimensional tensor is a mapping from a product of 512 vector spaces to R.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be more specific, you need to be clear on the terms *dimension*, *rank*, and *shape*.

The dimensionality of a tensor means the rank, which has a specific definition: the rank is the number of indices. When you see "3-dimensional tensor", you can take that to mean that the tensor has 3 indices, namely `T[i][j][k]`. So a vector has rank 1, a matrix has rank 2, a cube has rank 3, etc.

When you want to specify the size of each dimension, you should prefer to use the term `shape`. A 3-dimensional (aka rank 3) tensor can have shape [10, 20, 30] if the 0th dimension has 10 values, the 1st dimension has 20 values, and the 2nd dimension has 30 values. (This shape might represent, say, a batch of 10 images, each of shape 20x30.)

Note, though, that when talking about *vectors*, it is common to say "512-D vector". As you mentioned, this terminology comes up a lot with word embeddings (e.g. "we used 512-D word embeddings"). Since "vector" by definition means rank 1, then people will interpret that statement to mean "a structure of rank 1 with 512 values".

You might encounter someone saying "I have a 5-d vector", in which case you'd need to follow up with "wait, do you mean a 5-d tensor or a 1-d vector with 5 values?".

I am not a mathematician, by the way.