# Meaning of axis parameter switched in pd.DataFrame.all

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[True, np.nan, False],[True,np.nan,False],[True,np.nan,False]])
>>> df
      0   1      2
0  True NaN  False
1  True NaN  False
2  True NaN  False
```

According to the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html), doing `df.all(axis=1, skipna=True)` corresponds to checking if all values are true column-wise, so I expected it to give `True`,`True`,`False`, but it gives `False`,`False`,`False`.  It seems that the meaning of axis has been flipped, i.e. axis=0 is for columnwise.

This seems in contradiction with the meaning of axis in `DataFrame.dropna`, for example,

```
>>> df.dropna(axis=1)
      0      2
0  True  False
1  True  False
2  True  False
```

as well as in [`np.delete`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html).

Was this intentional?  And if so, why?

Comment: This looks like a mistake in the docs (could be a bug) there is a related issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25773245/ambiguity-in-pandas-dataframe-axis-definition?rq=1 about the apparent switching of meaning of axis and it is due to numpy, compare what happens when you try `np.all(df, axis=0)` and `np.all(df, axis=1)` the output is the same as pandas

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a mistake in the docs as this method will call [`numpy.all`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.all.html)  and if you compare the outputs they are the same:

```
In [211]:

np.all(df,axis=0)
Out[211]:
array([True, nan, False], dtype=object)
In [212]:

np.all(df, axis=1)
Out[212]:
array([False, False, False], dtype=object)
```

Also `dropna` and `np.delete` agree on the output:

```
In [213]:

df.dropna(axis=1)
Out[213]:
      0      2
0  True  False
1  True  False
2  True  False
In [222]:

np.delete(df.values, 1,axis=1)
Out[222]:
array([[True, False],
       [True, False],
       [True, False]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree it's not always very intuitive, but I think the behaviour is consistent.

`axis=0` works down the r0ws, `axis=1` works across the co1umns.

So, `df.all(axis=1, skipna=True)` returns `False, False, False` because it performs an action across all columns (here returning the result of `all(True, True, False)` at each row). Meanwhile, `df.all(axis=0, skipna=True)` looks down rows (for each column in turn). Only rows in column 2 contain `False` values, hence the result.

Similarly, `dropna(axis=1)` and `delete(axis=1)` initiate actions on columns (i.e. looking at each column for to see whether it should be dropped or deleted). Columns 0 and 2 do not contain any `NaN` values and so are retained, while column 1 disappears.