# What is the meaning of "axis" attribute in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, axis

Taking the following example:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
                        "y":[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}, 
                      index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({"y":[1, 3, 5, 7, 9], 
                        "z":[9, 8, 7, 6, 5]}, 
                      index=['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])

>>> pd.concat([df1, df2], join='inner')
```

The output is:

```
   y
a  3
b  4
c  5
d  6
e  7
b  1
c  3
d  5
e  7
f  9
```

Since `axis=0` is the columns, I think tha `concat()` only considers **columns** that are found in both dataframes. But the acutal output considers **rows** that are found in both dataframes.

What is the exactly meaning of `axis` parameter?

Comment: It's not about the axis argument. It's about ```join='inner'```. Look up the docs! ```join: {‘inner’, ‘outer’}, default ‘outer’. How to handle indexes on other axis(es). Outer for union and inner for intersection```

Comment: Think Roman Catholic. or "R" - "C" or  Row - Columns ->  Zero or One.

Answer (score 37):

If someone needs visual description, here is the image:

[image: Axis 0 or 1 in Pandas Python]

Comment: You can follow this link too:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149584/what-does-axis-in-pandas-mean

Answer (score 14):

Data:

```
In [55]: df1
Out[55]:
   x  y
a  1  3
b  2  4
c  3  5
d  4  6
e  5  7

In [56]: df2
Out[56]:
   y  z
b  1  9
c  3  8
d  5  7
e  7  6
f  9  5
```

Concatenated **horizontally** (axis=1), using **index elements** found in both DFs (aligned by indexes for joining):

```
In [57]: pd.concat([df1, df2], join='inner', axis=1)
Out[57]:
   x  y  y  z
b  2  4  1  9
c  3  5  3  8
d  4  6  5  7
e  5  7  7  6
```

Concatenated **vertically** (DEFAULT: axis=0), using **columns** found in both DFs:

```
In [58]: pd.concat([df1, df2], join='inner')
Out[58]:
   y
a  3
b  4
c  5
d  6
e  7
b  1
c  3
d  5
e  7
f  9
```

If you don't use the `inner` join method - you will have it this way:

```
In [62]: pd.concat([df1, df2])
Out[62]:
     x  y    z
a  1.0  3  NaN
b  2.0  4  NaN
c  3.0  5  NaN
d  4.0  6  NaN
e  5.0  7  NaN
b  NaN  1  9.0
c  NaN  3  8.0
d  NaN  5  7.0
e  NaN  7  6.0
f  NaN  9  5.0

In [63]: pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
Out[63]:
     x    y    y    z
a  1.0  3.0  NaN  NaN
b  2.0  4.0  1.0  9.0
c  3.0  5.0  3.0  8.0
d  4.0  6.0  5.0  7.0
e  5.0  7.0  7.0  6.0
f  NaN  NaN  9.0  5.0
```

Answer (score 11):

This is my trick with axis: just add the operation in your mind to make it sound clear:

- axis 0 = rows
- axis 1 = columns

If you “sum” through axis=0, you are summing all rows, and the output will be a single row with the same number of columns.
If you “sum” through axis=1, you are summing all columns, and the output will be a single column with the same number of rows.

Answer (score 4):

First, OP misunderstood the rows and columns in his/her dataframe.

> But the acutal output considers rows that are found in both dataframes.(the only common row element 'y')

OP thought the label `y` is for row. However, `y` is a column name.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
         {"x":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],  # <-- looks like row x but actually col x
          "y":[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}, # <-- looks like row y but actually col y
          index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
print(df1)

            \col   x    y
 index or row\
          a       1     3   |   a
          b       2     4   v   x
          c       3     5   r   i
          d       4     6   o   s
          e       5     7   w   0

               -> column
                 a x i s 1
```

It is very easy to be misled since in the dictionary, it looks like `y` and `x` are two rows.

If you generate `df1` from a list of list, it should be more intuitive:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,3], 
                    [2,4],
                    [3,5],
                    [4,6],
                    [5,7]],
                    index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], columns=["x", "y"])
```

So back to the problem, `concat` is a shorthand for *concatenate* (means to link together in a series or chain on this way [[source]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concatenate)) Performing `concat` **along** axis 0 means to linking two objects **along** axis 0.

```
   1
   1   <-- series 1
   1
^  ^  ^
|  |  |               1
c  a  a               1
o  l  x               1
n  o  i   gives you   2
c  n  s               2
a  g  0               2
t  |  |
|  V  V
v 
   2
   2   <--- series 2
   2
```

So... think you have the feeling now. What about [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) function in pandas? What does `sum(axis=0)` means?

Suppose data looks like

```
   1 2
   1 2
   1 2
```

Maybe...summing **along** axis 0, you may guess. Yes!!

```
^  ^  ^
|  |  |               
s  a  a               
u  l  x                
m  o  i   gives you two values 3 6 !
|  n  s               
v  g  0               
   |  |
   V  V
```

What about [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)? Suppose you have data

```
   1  2  NaN
  NaN 3   5
   2  4   6
```

and you only want to keep

```
2
3
4
```

On the documentation, it says *Return object with labels on given axis omitted where alternately any or all of the data are missing*

Should you put `dropna(axis=0)` or `dropna(axis=1)`? Think about it and try it out with

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, np.nan],
                   [np.nan, 3, 5],
                   [2, 4, 6]])

# df.dropna(axis=0) or df.dropna(axis=1) ?
```

Hint: think about the word *along*.

Answer (score 3):

Interpret axis=0 to apply the algorithm down each column, or to the row labels (the index).. A more detailed schema [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25774395/624829).

If you apply that general interpretation to your case, the algorithm here is `concat`. Thus for axis=0, it means:

*for each column, take all the rows down (across all the dataframes for `concat`) , and do contact them when they are in common (because you selected `join=inner`).*

So the meaning would be to take all columns `x` and concat them down the rows which would stack each chunk of rows one after another. However, here `x` is not present everywhere, so it is not kept for the final result. The same applies for `z`. For `y` the result is kept as `y` is in all dataframes. This is the result you have.