# Python Pandas: any(axis='rows') and any(axis='columns') give counter-intuitive outputs

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following outputs:

[image]

This is opposite to what I expect.

- If you're checking along the rows, and there are 3 rows, shouldn't you produce 3 Booleans?
- If you're checking along the columns, and there are 2 columns, shouldn't you produce 2 Booleans?

Please explain this seemingly counter-intuitive logic.

Comment: Please see :
[Ambiguity in Pandas Dataframe / Numpy Array “axis” definition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25774395/13194716)

Comment: This answer explains this counter-intuitive syntax. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46764691/12170242