# Pandas axes explained

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to understand the `axis` parameter in python `pandas`.  I understand that it's analogous to the numpy axis, but the following example still confuses me:

```
a = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 4], [1, 2, 3]])
print a

   0  1  2
0  0  1  4
1  1  2  3
```

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149584/what-does-axis-in-pandas-mean), `axis=0` runs along the rows (fixed column), while `axis=1` runs along the columns (fixed row).  Running `print a.drop(1, axis=1)` yields

```
   0  2
0  0  4
1  1  3
```

which results in a dropped column, while `print a.drop(1, axis=0)` drops a row.  Why? That seems backwards to me.

Comment: My main question is... if `axis=0` is thought of as column-wise, why then does `drop(1,axis=0)` drop a row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's slightly confusing, but `axis=0` operates on *rows*, `axis=1` operates on *columns*.

So when you use `df.drop(1, axis=1)` you are saying *drop column number 1*.

The other post has `df.mean(axis=1)`, which essentially says *calculate the mean on columns, per row*.

This is similar to indexing numpy arrays, where the first index specifies the row number (0th dimension), the second index the column number (1st dimension), and so on.

Comment: It seems to me that knowing when to add the *per row* or *per column* is completely arbitrary.