# How to select all rows which contain values *in selected columns* greater than a threshold?

Tags: python, pandas, filter, any

I'm trying to do the same thing as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613467/how-to-select-all-rows-which-contain-values-greater-than-a-threshold), but I have have a string-type column that I need to keep in the dataframe so I can identify which rows are which. (I guess I could do this by index, but I'd like to be able to save a step.) Is there a way to not count a column when using .any(), but keep it in the resulting dataframe? Thanks!

Here's the code that words on all columns:

```
df[(df > threshold).any(axis=1)]
```

Here's the hard coded version I'm working with right now:

```
df[(df[list_of__selected_columns] > 3).any(axis=1)]
```

This seems a little clumsy to me, so I'm wondering if there's a better way.

Comment: kindly share data, with expected output

Comment: my data is the same as the data in example of the first question linked to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42613567/12399409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.select_dtype` to choose all, say numerical columns:

```
df[df.select_dtype(include='number').gt(threshold).any(axis=1)]
```

Or a chunk of continuous columns with `iloc`:

```
df[df.iloc[:,3:6].gt(threshold).any(axis=1)]
```

If you want to select some random list of columns, you'd be best to resolve by hard coded list.