# Tensorflow: 'axis' argument in dot product

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, axis, dot-product

Can someone show me the way I should use the `axis` argument in [`tf.tensordot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot)?

I read the documentation but it was complicated and I'm still confused. I saw [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48082900/in-tensorflow-what-is-the-argument-axis-in-the-function-tf-one-hot) that asks about `axis` in `tf.one_hot` and in the answers were some good insights about the matter, but that didn't help me with `tf.tensordot`. I thought you can give me some insights on this too.

For example, I know I can dot product a vector and a tensor like this:

```
my_vector = tf.random.uniform(shape=[n])
my_tensor = tf.random.uniform(shape=[m, n])

dp = tf.tensordot(my_tensor, my_vector, 1)
```

But when I ***batch*** them and add one dimension to them to be of the shape `(b, n)` and `(b, m, n)` to obtain a `(b, m, 1)`, now I don't know how to dot product every batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation that you want to do cannot be done (in an effective way) with [`tf.tensordot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot). There is, however, a dedicated function for that operation, [`tf.linalg.matvec`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/matvec), which will work with batches out of the box. And you can also do the same thing with [`tf.einsum`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/einsum), like `tf.einsum('bmn,bn->bm', my_tensors, my_vectors)`.

With respect to [`tf.tensordot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot), in general it computes an "all vs all" product of the two given tensors, but matching and reducing some axes. When no axes are given (you have to explicitly pass `axes=[[], []]` to do this), it creates a tensor with the dimensions of both inputs concatenated. So, if you have `my_tensors` with shape `(b, m, n)` and `my_vectors` with shape `(b, n)` and you do:

```py
res = tf.tensordot(my_tensors, my_vectors, axes=[[], []])
```

You get `res` with shape `(b, m, n, b, n)`, such that `res[p, q, r, s, t] == my_tensors[p, q, r] * my_vectors[s, t]`.

The `axes` argument is used to specify dimensions in the input tensors that are "matched". Values along matched axes are multiplied and summed (like a dot product), so those matched dimensions are reduced from the output. `axes` can take two different forms:

- If it is a single integer, `N` then the last `N` dimensions of the first parameter are matched against the first `N` dimensions of `b`. In your example, that corresponds to the dimensions with `n` elements in `my_tensor` and `my_vector`.
- If it is a list, it must contain two sublists, `axes_a` and `axes_b`, each with the same number `N` of integers. In this form, you are explicitly indicating which dimensions of the given values are matched. So, in your example, you could have passed `axes=[[1], [0]]`, which means "match the dimension `1` of the first parameter (`my_tensor`) to the dimension `0` of the second parameter (`my_vector`)".

If you have now `my_tensors`  with shape `(b, m, n)` and `my_vectors` with shape `(b, n)`, then you would want to match the dimension `2` of the first one to the dimension `1` of the second one, so you could pass `axes=[[2], [1]]`. However, that will give you a result `res` with shape `(b, m, b)` such that `res[i, :, j]` is the product of matrix `my_tensors[i]` and vector `my_vectors[j]`. You could take then only the results that you want (those where `i == j`), with something more or less convoluted like `tf.transpose(tf.linalg.diag_part(tf.transpose(res, [1, 0, 2])))`, but you would be doing far more computation than you need to get the same result.

Comment: Your answer is great, thank you. But the result of your dot product is `(b, m, b)` shape. I want `(b, m, 1)` shape. How can I do that?

Comment: @Peymam You're right, I'm sorry, I didn't think that right... I'll fix the answer when I'm back in my computer. At least `matvec` and `einsum` should work...

Comment: @Peyman I updated the answer, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've found out `tf.keras.backend.batch_dot()` does the same thing but assuming the first dimension as batch.