# axis = 0 seems to behave different in sum() and dropna()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

From reading the pandas documentation, and a good question and answer ([What does axis in pandas mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149584/what-does-axis-in-pandas-mean)), I had expected axis=0 to always mean with respect to columns. This works for me when I work with sum(), but works the other way around when I use the dropna() call.

When i Have a dataframe like this:

```
raw_data = {'column1': [42,13, np.nan, np.nan],
        'column2': [4,12, np.nan, np.nan],
        'column3': [25,61, np.nan, np.nan]}
```

Which looks like this:

```
   column1  column2  column3
0     42.0      4.0     25.0
1     13.0     12.0     61.0
2      NaN      NaN      NaN
3      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

I can print the sums for the respective columns, with axis=0. And this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data )
print(df.sum(axis=0))
```

Gives the output:

```
column1    55.0
column2    16.0
column3    86.0
```

When I try to drop values from the dataframe with axis=0, this should again be with respect to columns*. But when I do:

```
dfclear=df.dropna(axis=0,how='all')
print(dfclear)
```

I get the output:

```
column1  column2  column3
0     42.0      4.0     25.0
1     13.0     12.0     61.0
```

Where I had expected the following (which I get with axis=1):

```
   column1  column2  column3
0     42.0      4.0     25.0
1     13.0     12.0     61.0
2      NaN      NaN      NaN
3      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

So it seems to me that axis behaves differently between sum() and dropna()

Is there something I'm missing here?

*https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html

Comment: I never got to an understanding of this. And as I read the answers they don't seem to adress why the axis command behaves differently between the two. Completely possible that I have just overlooked something.

Answer (score 1):

from the docstring:

```
In [41]: df.dropna?
Signature: df.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=False)
Docstring:
Return object with labels on given axis omitted where alternately any
or all of the data are missing

Parameters
----------
axis : {0 or 'index', 1 or 'columns'}, or tuple/list thereof
    Pass tuple or list to drop on multiple axes
...
```

if you are not sure what axis is, use the following method:

```
In [39]: df.dropna(axis='index', how='all')
Out[39]:
   column1  column2  column3
0     42.0      4.0     25.0
1     13.0     12.0     61.0

In [40]: df.dropna(axis='columns', how='all')
Out[40]:
   column1  column2  column3
0     42.0      4.0     25.0
1     13.0     12.0     61.0
2      NaN      NaN      NaN
3      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: In the pandas docs, it says for dropna:
axis : {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}
and for sum:
axis : {index (0), columns (1)}
So it should be the same for both. Though in my example they behave opposite of each other, as far as I can see.

Comment: @Simon, it looks correct to me: `Return object with labels on given axis omitted`

Comment: Okay. But did you see the part in my question with sum? Thats returns results for each column, not for each row, and that's with axis = 0

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is correct :

```
print(df)
```

produces below output:

```
   column1  column2  column3
0     42.0      4.0     25.0
1     13.0     12.0     61.0
2      NaN      NaN      NaN
3      NaN      NaN      NaN

dfclear=df.dropna(axis=0,how='all')
print(dfclear)
```

Produces below output:

```
   column1  column2  column3
0     42.0      4.0     25.0
1     13.0     12.0     61.0
```

From Pandas Documentation Sample Explaination :

> Drop the rows where all of the elements are nan (there is no row to
>   drop, so df stays the same)

Answer (score 0):

Mind you, pandas shift also has counter intuitive axis meaning, where 0 means by raw and 1 means by column.

I guess they need to address these and other similar points in their documentation somewhere