# why pandas.DataFrame.sum(axis=0) returns sum of values in each column where axis =0 represent rows?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, data-analysis

In pandas, **axis=0 represent rows** and **axis=1 represent columns**.
Therefore **to get the sum of values in each row in pandas**, **df.sum(axis=0)** is called.
**But it returns a sum of values in each columns** and vice-versa. **Why???**

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame({"x":[1,2,3,4,5],"y":[2,4,6,8,10]})
df.sum(axis=0)
```

Dataframe:

```
   x   y
0  1   2

1  2   4

2  3   6

3  4   8

4  5  10
```

Output:

```
x    15

y    30
```

Expected Output:

```
0     3

1     6

2     9

3    12

4    15
```

Comment: Axis=0 doesn't represent rows in the way you are thinking of them. If you want to sum all the values in a row, or apply a function to each row, use axis=1. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149584/what-does-axis-in-pandas-mean/52506118 for more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does axis in pandas mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149584/what-does-axis-in-pandas-mean)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the right way to interpret the `axis` parameter is what axis you sum 'over' (or 'across'), rather than the 'direction' the sum is computed in. Specifying `axis = 0` computes the sum over the rows, giving you a total for each column; `axis = 1` computes the sum across the columns, giving you a total for each row.

Answer (score 2):

I was a reading the source code in pandas project, and I think that this come from Numpy, in this library is used in that way(0 sum vertically and 1 horizonally), and additionally Pandas use under the hood numpy in order to make this sum.

In this [link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py#L10149) you could check that pandas use `numpy.cumsum` function to make the sum.
And this [link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) is for numpy documentation.

If you are looking a way to remember how to use the axis parameter, the 'anant' answer, its a good approach, interpreting the sum `over` the axis instead `across`. So when is specified 0 you are computing the sum over the rows(iterating over the index in order to be more pandas doc complaint). When axis is 1 you are iterating over the columns.