# I'm comfused about axis=0 and axis=1

Tags: dataframe

the `axis=1` below is to find if there's any NaN in every row.

```
df.isnull().any(axis=1)
```

the `axis=1` below is to drop column if there is missing value.

```
df1.dropna(axis=1, how='any')
```

I am so confused! usually I think axis=0 is relating to rows, axis=1 is relating to columns.
Can you explain me why `axis=1` is relating to row in the first example, and relating to column in the second example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does axis in pandas mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149584/what-does-axis-in-pandas-mean)

Comment: because IMHO, pandas have inconsistent `api`.