# what is the difference between notna() and dropna()?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on titanic data right now, using pandas. Funny thing is, when dealing with missing values, drorpna() does not work but notna() does.

```
temp.Embarked.dropna(inplace = True)
temp.isnull().sum()
```

Embarked      2

```
temp = temp[temp['Embarked'].notna()]
temp.isnull().sum()
```

Embarked      0

Comment: `temp.Embarked.dropna(inplace = True)` does nothing since it works on a slice of the dataframe. `temp.dropna(subset=['Embarked'], inplace=True)` might.

Comment: @QuangHoang well, not a slice, but a single column, but yeah

Comment: Simply [`notna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) will return True if element is not null , while [`dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) removes elements which are null.

Answer (score 1):

I think both done same process, but when we are using `dropna()` we have to mention how the way we have to drop Nan means, by axis....

you have to mention row wise or column wise

Eg:`temp.Embarked.dropna(inplace = True,axis=1)`

it will drop the nan values with entire row

for further clarification please refer this link below:

Here's [What does axis in pandas mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149584/what-does-axis-in-pandas-mean)