# How to assigne a dataframe mean to specific rows of dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, row, mean, unassigned-variable

I have a data frame like this

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 4, 5, 6, 12],
                 'b': [3, 5, 7, 9, 15]})

    Out[112]: 
    a   b
0   2   3
1   4   5
2   5   7
3   6   9
4  12  15
```

and mean out

```
df_a.mean()

Out[118]: 
a   5.800
b   7.800
dtype: float64
```

I want this;

```
df_a[df_a.index.isin([3, 4])] = df.mean()
```

But I'm getting an error. How do I achieve this?
I gave an example here. There are observations that I need to change a lot in the data that I am working with. And I keep their index values in a list

Comment: `df_a.loc[4] = df_a.mean()`?

Comment: If you don't want to overwrite data that went into the calculation `df_a.append(df_a.mean().rename('mean'))` OR `df_a.append(df_a.mean().rename(len(df_a)))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does axis in pandas mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149584/what-does-axis-in-pandas-mean)

Comment: I fixed the question sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to overwrite the values of rows in a list, you can do it with `iloc`

```py
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'a': [2, 4, 5, 6, 12], 'b': [3, 5, 7, 9, 15]})

idx_list = [3, 4]
df_a.iloc[idx_list,:] = df_a.mean()
```

Output

```
     a    b
0  2.0  3.0
1  4.0  5.0
2  5.0  7.0
3  5.8  7.8
4  5.8  7.8
```

## edit

If you're using an older version of `pandas` and see `NaN`s instead of wanted values, you can use a `for` loop

```
df_a_mean = df_a.mean()
for i in idx_list:
    df_a.iloc[i,:] = df_a_mean
```

Comment: But I must use df_a[df_a.index.isin([3, 4])] in my data There are a lot of indexes

Comment: @HikmetSelimTalu do you want to impute the mean to outliers?

Comment: Yes, but I gave an example here. There are observations that I need to change a lot in the data that I am working with. And I keep their index values in a list

Comment: I've tried this before, but that's how I get the result in python.

Comment: You wrote `df_a[df_a.index.isin([3, 4])]`, try `iloc` solution I wrote instead. If you have got the indexes `iloc` is the best method

Comment: I shared a photo

Comment: `pandas` version?

Comment: 1.1.3 version of pandas

Comment: This is the issue: I'm using 1.2.3 and `iloc` is working correctly. I tried with your version and I get `NaN`s. Update `pandas` if you can.

Comment: I added solution for older pandas versions

Comment: Thanks Max Pierini I fixed this problem,
df_a.loc[idx, df.columns] = df[df.columns].mean().tolist()
it worked