# Use of dim=0/1 in pytorch and nn.softmax?

Tags: python, pytorch

When using nn.softmax(), we use dim=1 or 0. Here dim=0 should mean row according to intuition but seems it means along the column. Is this true?

```
>>> x = torch.tensor([[1,2],[3,4]],dtype=torch.float)
>>> F.softmax(x,dim=0)
tensor([[0.1192, 0.1192],
        [0.8808, 0.8808]])
>>> F.softmax(x,dim=1)
tensor([[0.2689, 0.7311],
        [0.2689, 0.7311]])
```

Here when dim=0, probabilities along the columns sum to 1. Similarly when dim=1 probabilities along the rows sum to 1. Can someone explain how dim is used in PyTorch?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does axis in pandas mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149584/what-does-axis-in-pandas-mean)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, in the 2D case: row refers to `axis=0`, while column refers to `axis=1`.

The `dim` option specifies along which dimension the softmax is apply, *i.e.* **summing back on that same axis will lead to `1`s**:

```
>>> x = torch.arange(1, 7, dtype=float).reshape(2,3)
tensor([[1., 2., 3.],
        [4., 5., 6.]], dtype=torch.float64)
```

On `axis=0`:

```
>>> F.softmax(x, dim=0).sum(0)
tensor([1.0000, 1.0000, 1.0000], dtype=torch.float64)
```

On `axis=1`:

```
>>> F.softmax(x, dim=1).sum(1)
>>> tensor([1.0000, 1.0000], dtype=torch.float64)
```

This is the expected behavior for [`torch.nn.functional.softmax`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.softmax.html?highlight=softmax#torch.nn.functional.softmax)

> [...]
> Parameters:
>
> - `dim` (*int*) – A dimension along which `Softmax` will be computed (so every slice along dim will sum to `1`).

Comment: I did notice it when I used it in argmax() for getting the predicted class.