# DAX equivlent for Countif in excel

Tags: dax, countif

=COUNTIF(J11:AI11,">0")
column headings are Wk1,..,W26
I want to count the number of cells that are greater than 0

I see lot of example of counting within a column, I need to count instances in a row(s) and create a new column.

Answer (score 0):

what about unpivoting those columns in Power Query, then you can apply COUNTX function?
Check this site: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098

After unpivoting, the solution would be

COUNTX(
FILTER(table,table[Values]>0);table[Values])

Or you can run Pandas script in Power Query and run a count across rows, see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-python-in-query-editor

Thread regarding to row-wise operations in Pandas:
[What does axis in pandas mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149584/what-does-axis-in-pandas-mean)