# df.mean() giving nan values even for non-nan input

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, mean

I am calculating the mean of each row in a data frame, but even when all the values in the row are valid numeric values, the mean is still coming out to be nan.
[image]

The datatype is float64 for all the columns, but the mean is coming out to be nan for all the rows. (the last column in the image is the mean) I have excluded the first column (timestamp column) from the calculation. I also tried specifying skipna=True, but even that is not working.

The statement I have used is df[].mean(axis=0,skipna=True). *Some* of the rows have some nan values, but the sum of these row counts is only a tiny fraction of the total row count, and I would expect the skipna=True part to take care of the nans.

Any reasons why this could be happening and how to proceed?

Comment: Row means should be `axis=1`, not 0.

Comment: It's coming out `nan` because you computed column means, so the index of that resulting series is the column names. Then when you assign that to a column, it tries to align those column names with the row indexes and can't do it, so it just gives all `nan`.

Comment: Related: [Why does `mean(axis=1)` compute row means instead of column means?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22149584/13138364)

Answer (score 0):

you can use, its work for me:

```
df['mean'] = df.iloc[:, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]].mean(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks
I had entered the wrong axis for calculating the mean. Was able to do it without the iloc as well.

Answer (score 0):

**A working demo is as follows:**

```
import pandas as pd

df_example = pd.DataFrame({
    'DateTime': ['2018-09-15 12:00:00', '2018-09-15 13:00:00', '2018-09-15 14:00:00', '2018-09-15 15:00:00', '2018-09-15 16:00:00', '2018-09-15 17:00:00', '2018-09-15 18:00:00', '2018-09-15 19:00:00', '2018-09-15 20:00:00'],   
    'Num1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    'Num2': [6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
})

df_example['Mean'] = df_example[['Num1', 'Num2']].mean(axis=1)

print(df_example)
```

**Output**

```
              DateTime  Num1  Num2  Mean
0  2018-09-15 12:00:00     1     6   3.5
1  2018-09-15 13:00:00     2     6   4.0
2  2018-09-15 14:00:00     3     6   4.5
3  2018-09-15 15:00:00     4     6   5.0
4  2018-09-15 16:00:00     5     6   5.5
5  2018-09-15 17:00:00     6     6   6.0
6  2018-09-15 18:00:00     7     6   6.5
7  2018-09-15 19:00:00     8     6   7.0
8  2018-09-15 20:00:00     9     6   7.5
```

Comment: Thanks - it was happening because I entered wrong axis.

I used a similar approach to yours - created a list of columns to be averaged and stored it in a separate variable, and passed this to subset the df for calculating the mean.