# Why does element-wise division on dataframes yields NaNs even when the indices are the same?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm confused about why `result_col` is all NaNs and `result_row` gives the expected result. In other questions here, the NaN result has been attributed to "misaligned indices." I'm confused about what that means, since the row index for `df` and `df['D']` are the same.

```
data = {'A': [2, 3, 4], 'B': [10, 20, 30], 'C': [5, 4, 1], 'D': [1, 1, 1]}

# create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.astype(float)

# divide each column by column D
result_col = df.div(df['D'], axis=1)
result_row = df.div(df['D'], axis=0)

print(result_col)
print(result_row)
```

These were the results. I expected the second set of results (i.e. the floats) for both.

```
    A   B   C   D   0   1   2
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

```
     A     B    C    D
0  2.0  10.0  5.0  1.0
1  3.0  20.0  4.0  1.0
2  4.0  30.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Maybe you're unclear on what `axis` does? Check out: [What does axis in pandas mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22149584/13138364)

Comment: `df['D']` has index values of 0, 1, and 2. When you divide by `df['D']` using `axis=1`, it looks for _columns_ 0, 1, and 2, but they don't exist.