# lack of knowledge what do dimesions really represent

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dimensions

2d array, consists of 2 axes, axis=0 which represents the rows and the axis=1 represents the columns

```
aa = np.random.randn(10, 2) # Here is 2d array, first axis has 10 rows and second axis has 2 columns

array([[ 0.6999521 , -0.17597954],
       [ 1.70622947, -0.85919459],
       [-0.90019284,  0.80774052],
       [-1.42953238,  0.19727917],
       [-0.03416532,  0.49584749],
       [-0.28981586, -0.77484498],
       [-1.31129122,  0.423833  ],
       [-0.43920016, -1.93541758],
       [-0.06667634,  2.09925218],
       [ 1.24633485, -0.04153847]])
```

why when I want to scatter the points I only consider the first column and the second column dimension from axis=1? do dimensions mean columns when plotting and at other times they mean axes? can you please explain more the reasons to do it like this? and if there are good references I could benefit myself on dimensions relating to this

```
plt.scatter(x[:,0], x[:,1])  # this also means dimensions or columns?

x[:,0], x[:,1] why not do x[0,:], x[:,1}
```

Comment: `x[:,0]` is a 1d array.  For scatter it doesn't matter whether the 1d array is made diectly with `np.array([1,2,3])` or indiectly from the columns or rows of the 2d array.

Comment: `x[0,:]` has 2 elements, the 1st 'row'.  `x[:,1]` has 10.  You can't 'scatter' 10 against 2.  `scatter` wants 2 1d arrays that match in length.

Answer (score 0):

It can be difficult to visualize this, especially in multiple dimensions.

The parameters to the `[]` operator represent the dimensions.  Your first dimension is the rows.  The first row is `array[0]`. Your second dimension is the columns.  The entire second column is called `array[:,1]` -- the ":" is a numpy notation that means "take all of this dimension".  `array[2,1]` refers to the second column in the third row.

`plt.scatter` expects the x coordinate values as its first parameter, and the y coordinate values as its second parameter.   `plt.scatter(x[:,0], x[:,1])` means "take all of column 0" and "take all of column 1", which is the way `scatter` wants them.

Comment: yes you didn't answer my question, why take the columns x[:,0], x[:,1] and not take rows and columns which represent the 2 axes/dims of the 2d array?

Comment: Because those are the arguments that plt.scatter expects.  It wants two arrays, where each element in the first array matches the corresponding element in the second array.  It could have been written differently, but it wasn't.

Comment: aha, where can I learn more about this? I can't find this in linear algebra, are there any good references that explain dimensionality? because I also have problems understanding which axis to choose to do mean/sum!!

Comment: `numpy` arrays are more grneral than linear algebra matrices and vectors (or more abstract).  Don't try to find 'meaning' else where.

Comment: Axis 0 is dimension 0 -- the rows in your case.   Axis 1 is dimension 1 -- the columns in your case.   `sum(aa,axis=1)` would produce two elements with sums of the columns.  `sum(aa,axis=0)` would produce 10 elements, when the sum of the coordinates for each point.  Playing with it is probably the best way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

With this `randn` call you make a 2d array with the specified shape.  The dimensions, 10 and 2, don't represent anything - that's an abstract (10,2) array.  Meaning comes from how you use it.

```
In [50]: aa = np.random.randn(10, 2)
In [51]: aa
Out[51]: 
array([[-0.26769106,  0.09882999],
       [-1.5605514 , -1.38614473],
       [ 1.23312852,  0.86838848],
       [ 1.2603898 ,  2.19895989],
       [-1.66937976,  0.79666952],
       [-0.15596669,  1.47848784],
       [ 1.74964902,  0.39280584],
       [-1.0982447 ,  0.46888408],
       [ 0.84396231, -0.34809148],
       [-0.83489678, -1.8093045 ]])
```

That's a display - with rows and columns.

Rather than pass the slices directly to `scatter` lets assign them to variables:

```
In [52]: x = aa[:,0]; y = aa[:,1]; x,y
Out[52]: 
(array([-0.26769106, -1.5605514 ,  1.23312852,  1.2603898 , -1.66937976,
        -0.15596669,  1.74964902, -1.0982447 ,  0.84396231, -0.83489678]),
 array([ 0.09882999, -1.38614473,  0.86838848,  2.19895989,  0.79666952,
         1.47848784,  0.39280584,  0.46888408, -0.34809148, -1.8093045 ]))
```

We now have two 1d arrays with shape (10,) (that's a 1 element tuple).  We can then plot them with:

```
In [53]: plt.scatter(x,y)
```

I could just as well used

```
x = np.arange(10); y = np.random.randn(10)
```

to make two 1d arrays.

The dimensions of the `aa` array have nothing to do with the axes of a scatter plot.

I could select a 'row' of `aa`, but will only get a (2,) shape array.  That can't be plotted against a (10,) array:

```
In [53]: aa[0,:]
Out[53]: array([-0.26769106,  0.09882999])
```

As for meaning of dimensions in `sum/mean`, why not experiement?

Sum all values:

```
In [54]: aa.sum()
Out[54]: 2.2598841819604134
```

sum down the columns, resulting in one value per column:

```
In [55]: aa.sum(axis=0)
Out[55]: array([-0.49960074,  2.75948492])
```

It can help to `keepdims`, producing a (1,2) array:

```
In [56]: aa.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True)
Out[56]: array([[-0.49960074,  2.75948492]])
```

or a (10,1) array:

```
In [57]: aa.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
Out[57]: 
array([[-0.16886107],
       [-2.94669614],
       [ 2.101517  ],
       [ 3.45934969],
       [-0.87271024],
       [ 1.32252115],
       [ 2.14245486],
       [-0.62936062],
       [ 0.49587083],
       [-2.64420128]])
```

There's some ambiguity when talking about summing along rows or columns when dealing with 2d arrays.  It becomes clearer when we apply `sum` to 1d arrays (sum the only one), or 3d.

For example, note which dimension is missing when I do:

```
In [58]: np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4).sum(axis=1).shape
Out[58]: (2, 4)
```

or

```
In [59]: np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4).sum(axis=2)
Out[59]: 
array([[ 6, 22, 38],
       [54, 70, 86]])
```

Again - dimensions of numpy arrays are abstract things.  An array can have 0, 1, 2 or more (up to 32) dimensions.  Most of linear algebra deals with 2d arrays, matrices and "vectors".  You can do LA with `numpy`, but `numpy` is used for much more.

### edit

You could think of your `aa` as 10 2-element points.  Then `aa[:,0]` are all the `x` coordinates.  A mean with axis=0 would be the "center of mass" of those points.

```
In [60]: np.mean(aa, axis=0)
Out[60]: array([-0.04996007,  0.27594849])
```

Mean on axis=1 may not make sense, though you could calculate the norm of the points (`sqrt(x^2+y^2)`), or the length of the vectors represented by the points.

```
In [61]: np.linalg.norm(aa, axis=1)
Out[61]: 
array([0.28535218, 2.08727523, 1.50821235, 2.53456249, 1.84973271,
       1.48669159, 1.79320052, 1.19414978, 0.91292938, 1.99264533])
```

For direction of these points I'd use:

```
np.arctan2(aa[:,0], aa[:,1])
```

(or maybe switch the 0 and 1).

Comment: thanks for the prompt response, 
I understand this but I want to be able to find the relation between the dimensions and axes and the operations made among them. 
but which type of problems suit taking the sum across the 1st dim(axis=0)/2nd(axis=1), 3rd(axis=-1)  ex, calculating the distances between points, it's always calculated across the second axis, why? when should I calculate across the rows, (axis=0)? I'd really appreciate your answer

Comment: What are you calling points?  Are you think of the `aa` array as 10 points, with each point represented as 2 values?  What the "dimensions" mean is in your head, not in `numpy`.  What if you made a (2,10) array, and plotted `bb[0,:]` against `bb[1,:]`?  Either can represent 10 2-element points.  3 dimensions could represent something else, for example a (400,600,3) array might be a 400x600 color image.

Comment: if we take the scatter plot of bb[0,:] and bb[1,:] we would have plotted the points projected on the x axis

Comment: I think of aa as 10 points with coordinates on 2 axes (dimensions: x, y) if we are in a 2d array but what are the types of problems that require us to calculate the distances between points on the second axis and not on the first axis? when I have something like this (400,600,3) or with batches (6,400,600,3) what are the reasons that make me average across the first axis/2nd/3rd? like is it a rule that you always take the mean across the first dim (axis=0) a rule to take differences.sum(axis=1) between points across the first dim?

Comment: What operation makes sense for a particular array axis depends on what meaning YOU assigned to the axis.  `numpy` by itself doesn't determine that. I added to my answer a `norm` taken on axis 1.  `atan2` could be used to get the angle, direction, of those 10 'points'.

Comment: I'm aware that the option axis = ... doesn't know about the information you have in the matrix, I mean it doesn't consider that you have points in the matrix. It just makes the function operate over the designated axis if you want rows to use axis=0. If columns, axis=1
and it's a problem that I'm facing, when I'm in a situation calculating the distances/max/min I usually don't know what axis to choose in order for an operation (min,max,...) to do its job, obviously there's no rule to follow for me to know

Comment: and I know it depends on the problem I'm dealing with! 
but this lack of knowledge in which book  (because I don't know the concept name for this to look for) does it lie and if you can recommend me a good book/article that helped you just to understand on which axis should I depend doing the axes calculations I'd be thankful

Comment: quoting you; I added to my answer a norm taken on axis 1. atan2 could be used to get the angle, direction, of those 10 'points'. then how would you know like what does this axis =1 (columns) represents solving the problem of getting the angle or the direction of the 10 points for you to choose this axis?

Comment: because axis=1 ==> columns ==> collapse columns so how to know which axis to collapse?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19389910/in-python-numpy-what-is-a-dimension-and-axis like this if there's more info to it!!!

Comment: I know that `aa` has shape (10,2), and the you/we consider this to represent 10 2-element points.  If I want a separate result for each "point', 10 in total, I'll use `axis=1` for reduction operation like `norm`, or pass `aa[:,i]` arrays to the function.  If I want a size 2 result, some sort of summary overall points, axis=0 most likely is the correct choice.  Sometimes I have to experiment with small cases where the choice is obvious.  Playing with just 2 points in a (2,2) array would be confusing.

Comment: Thank You, I needed this.  and if you happen to know a book in the future to expand my knowledge on this I'd appreciate it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250634/discussion-between-user4556432-and-hpaulj).