# How to use the dimension of a python matrix in a loop

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I am working with a matrix, lets call it X, in python.

I know how to get the dimension of the matrix using X.shape but I am interested specially on using the number of rows of the matrix in a for loop, and I dont know how to get this value in a datatype suitable for a loop.

For example, imagine tihs simple situation:

```
a = np.matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
for i in 1:(number of rows of a)
     print i
```

How can I get automatically that "number of rows of a"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy array dimensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061761/numpy-array-dimensions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A superficial search on [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) will lead you to [`shape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html). It returns a *tuple of array dimensions*.

In your case, the first dimension (axe) concerns the columns. You can access it as you access a tuple's element:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.matrix([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
# a. shape[1]: columns
for i in range(0,a.shape[1]):
   print 'column '+format(i)

# a. shape[0]: rows   
for i in range(0, a.shape[0]):
   print 'row '+format(i)
```

This will print:

```
column 0
column 1
column 2
row 0
row 1
```

Answer (score 2):

X.shape[0] == number of rows in X