# how to get the numbers of columns and rows of an array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

I have come accross a line code that actually works for the work I am doing but I do not understand it. I would like someone to please explain what it means.

```
b=(3,1,2,1)

a=2

q=np.zeros(b+(a,))
```

I would like to know why length of q is always the first entry of b.

```
for example len(q)=3

if b=(1,2,4,3) then len(q)=1
```

This is really confusing as I thought that the function 'len' returns the number of columns of a given array. Also, how do I get the number of rows of q. So far the only specifications I have found are len(q), q.size( which gives the total number of elements in q) and q.shape(which also I do not quite get the output, because in the latter case, q.shape=(b,a)=(1,2,4,3,2).

Is there  function that could return the size of the array in terms of the numberof columns and  rows? for example 24x2?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy array dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061761/numpy-array-dimensions)

Answer (score 2):

In Python a array does only have one dimension, that's why len(array) returns a single number.

Assuming that you have a 'matrix' in form of array of arrays, like this:

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

declared like

```
mat = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

you can determine the 'number of columns and rows' by the following commands:

```
rows = len(mat)
columns = len(mat[0])
```

Note that it only works if number of elements in each row is constant

Answer (score 1):

If you are using numpy to make the arrays, another way to get the column rows and columns is using the tuple from the `np.shape()` function. Here is a complete example:

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
rownum = np.shape(mat)[0]
colnum = np.shape(mat)[1]
```